# Why is `kprobes_register` (kprobes) able to retrieve symbol addresses for symbols like `flush_tlb_all`, but not `sys_call_table`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Consider the following kernel module source, which uses `kprobes_register` to get the address of a kernel symbol.

It works for symbols like `flush_tlb_all`, but not for `sys_call_table`.

A quick lookup using `/proc/kallsyms`:

```
sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep -E '\sflush_tlb_all$|\ssys_call_table$'
ffffffff86a83e20 T flush_tlb_all
ffffffff87a002e0 D sys_call_table
```

The difference being (`man nm`) that `flush_tlb_all` is in the `text` section, where as `sys_call_table` is in the `data` section. However, both symbols are global (external).

Why can't `kprobes_register` be used to lookup the address of `sys_call_table`?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>

#define MAX_SYMBOL_LEN  64
static char symbol[MAX_SYMBOL_LEN] = "flush_tlb_all";
module_param_string(symbol, symbol, sizeof(symbol), 0644);

/* For each probe you need to allocate a kprobe structure */
static struct kprobe kp = {
   .symbol_name = symbol,
};

static int __init kprobe_init(void)
{
   int ret;

   ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
   if (ret < 0) {
      pr_err("register_kprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
      return ret;
   }
   pr_info("Planted kprobe at %p\n", kp.addr);
   return 0;
}

static void __exit kprobe_exit(void)
{
   unregister_kprobe(&kp);
   pr_info("kprobe at %p unregistered\n", kp.addr);
}

module_init(kprobe_init);
module_exit(kprobe_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference being (`man nm`) that `flush_tlb_all` is in the `text` section, where as `sys_call_table` is in the `data` section. However, both symbols are global (external).

This is exactly why `register_kprobe` fails on `sys_call_table`: it only allows probes in the kernel text. [`kprobe_register`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/kernel/kprobes.c#L1629) calls [`check_kprobe_address_safe`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/kernel/kprobes.c#L1557) once it has the address to probe, and the latter checks that the address is part of the kernel text.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt. How is it possible to retrieve address of global symbols in the data section? Normally kallsyms would allow that, however its API is not exported to modules anymore. Maybe I should do a kprobe for the kallsyms functions and see where that leads me. I need this, because I want to experience with dynamically patching syscalls.

Comment: An approach [similar to this one](https://github.com/0xabe-io/syscall-hooks/blob/master/hook_module.c) should still work, as long as you change the syscall table to be writable.

Comment: Thanks. However, the approach is extremely dependent on the given kernel for the searched kernel-memory range (between two symbols). I did it by using kprobe to get the non-exported `kallsyms_lookup_name`, and then used that to get the `sys_call_table`. However, my solution depends on kallsyms and kprobes having been configured for the given kernel.

Comment: ~@StephenKitt - Regarding your approach, it seems that `sys_call_table[__NR_close]==__x64_sys_close` and that `sys_close` is not exported anymore from `syscalls.h`? Furthermore, `ksys_close` is not equal to `__x64_sys_close`, so I have no real way of comparing `sys_call_table[__NR_close]` to a known symbol? Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: That’s a good point, syscalls are no longer exported to modules. I don’t know of a workaround.

Comment: I guess, my approach of coupling `kprobes` with `kallsyms` is the only one that works then. Seems developers don't like the idea of hooking syscalls or otherwise tamper with internal kernel behaviour.

Comment: Apparently, unless you use eBPF hooks ;-).

Comment: Thanks. Will you provide a link to an example of using eBPF hooks for hooking syscalls (if you know of any)?

Comment: There’s a bunch of them in `bcc`, for example [`solisten.py`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/solisten.py).