# Calling Linux kernel methods from a kernel module

Tags: kernel-modules, c

What is the right way of calling kernel functions in a C file from a kernel module in Linux?

I want to call `exit_task_namespaces` in `linux/nsproxy.c` from my first ever kernel module

I am doing this:

```c
#include <linux/nsproxy.h>
…

static ssize_t device_read(struct file *flip, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    struct task_struct *task = current;
    …
    exit_task_namespaces(task);
    …
}
```

when I try to `make` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: "exit_task_namespaces" [/home/.../lkm_example.ko] undefined!
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1673: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-73-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 2
```

I can see that in the file `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-73-generic/include/linux/nsproxy.h` the method exists.

This is my Makefile:

```
obj-m += lkm_example.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Comment: As an aside, you should really be using `$(MAKE)` rather than `make` in your sub-make invocation.

Comment: [How the `MAKE` Variable Works](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html).  For example: - `$(MAKE)` implicitly has `+` at the beginning, so it will run `make -n` when invoked by `make -n`, so you can see all the commands that will run.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight... I (think) understand now - thanks for sharing!

Comment: `exit_task_namespaces` being called from a module is massively wrong; there is no way this would ever be exported for module use. It's a subroutine of the `do_exit` logic for terminating a process. Calling these functions randomly on a running task could leave it in a bad state with something depending on the cleaned-up resources to still be there. It's very curious how you arrived at the idea of targeting this specific function from a module.

Comment: Hi @Kaz! Very good point :)  maybe I should have added the reason into the question. I am simply trying to learn the kernel code - this module will never be used for any real thing. I am a still trying to figure out what is the best way to dig into the code, so I am trying to create a module, add some traces and start calling here and there to check results. For example, I changed the `task->nsproxy` from the module and it did not do what i expected :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Modules can only access [exported symbols](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kernel-hacking/hacking.html#symbols), and `exit_task_namespaces` isn’t exported — so even though it is visible in the header files, it can’t be used in a module.

Exported symbols can be accessed as you’d expect, there’s nothing special to do.

Comment: Thank you @StephenKitt! A new thing to learn :)

Comment: Note: you can use kallsyms_get_name() if you really HAVE to, but it's considered a bad practice.

Comment: @kiler129 I’m guessing you’re referring to `kallsyms_lookup_name` — but that is no longer exported to modules, so it’s not only considered bad practice, it’s become rather difficult, although [there are still workarounds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/643206/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt: And last time I checked you can build a stripped kernel that doesn't even have non-exported symbols in the symbol table.

Comment: @Joshua you can indeed!